# Max(F(x),F(y)) is a joint CDF?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

If F(•) is a cumulative distribution function:

•) Is F(x,y) =max[F(x),F(y)] a joint cumulative distribution function?

I intuitively think that it is not a cumulative distribution function

:( I have no idea how to start this exercise, for your help, thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

If $F(x,y)$ is a joint cdf, and $x_1<x_2$ and $y_1<y_2$, then you must have
$$
F(x_2,y_2)-F(x_1,y_2)-F(x_2,y_1)+F(x_1,y_1)\ge 0,
$$
since the LHS is the probability of an event (what event?). Let $y_1=x_1$ and $y_2=x_2$, and show the above is not satisfied in general for your joint cdf.

---

Perhaps even simpler; any joint cdf must satisfy
$$
\lim_{x\to-\infty} F(x,y)=0
$$
for any fixed $y$. But $\lim_{x\to-\infty}\max(F(x),F(y))=F(y)$.

Answer (score -1):

We already know that 
$$
\lim_{x\to \infty} F(x)=1.
$$
The thing to note is that to be a joint CDF, we must have
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty, y\to \infty}F(x,y)=1
$$

Here is the proof: we have
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty, y\to \infty}F(x,y)
=\lim_{x\to\infty, y\to \infty}\max(F(x),F(y))\geq\lim_{x\to \infty} F(x)=1,
$$
since $\max(F(x),F(y))\geq F(x)$.

But we also have $F(x)\leq 1$ for all $x$, so $\max(F(x),F(y))\leq 1$.

This means $\lim_{x\to\infty, y\to \infty}F(x,y)=1$.

There are other details to consider. $F(x,y)$ need to be increasing with $x$ and $y$. So, let's suppose that for some $x_1<x_2$, $F(x_1,y)>F(x_2,y)$. A moment's thought could lead to that we must have $F(x_1)\leq F(y)$ and $F(x_2)\geq F(y)$, a contradiction. (I have omitted the details) Actually, in general, the "max" of two increasing functions is increasing.

The conclusion is that $F(x,y)$ is a joint CDF. The same is, however, not true for PDF.

Comment: Yeah, it's good, but in the book the answer is that F(x,y) is not a joint CDF

Comment: @LuisRodriguezFuentes Can you check if I am wrong? Can you also tell me the definition of joint CDF in your book? It might depend on the definition you use.

Comment: Is the same definition, the book add this.    F(x+,y)=F(x,y).    F(x,y+)=F(x,y)

Comment: @LuisRodriguezFuentes Have your book given a reason?

Comment: No, only give the answer "No"

Comment: @LuisRodriguezFuentes Then maybe you can check if I am wrong.

Comment: The definition of a joint cdf is unambiguous; it is $F(x,y)=P(X\le x\cap Y\le y)$ for a random vector $(X,Y)$. Every joint cdf satisfies four conditions; (i) The limit as all variables $\to+\infty$ of $F$ is $1$ (ii) The limit as any variable to $-\infty$ of $F$ is zero (iii) $F$ is right continuous in all variables (iv) The condition given in my answer must hold (this is stronger than being increasing in each variable). You have only verified condition (i); this is your mistake.

Comment: @MikeEarnest Yes you are right. My statistics has been rusty for a long time. Let me edit my answer.